# Why is __setattr__ called on an attribute which is an instance of another class

Tags: python-3.x

I very puzzled by the fact that `__setattr__` is being called in an attempt to set a class attribute, which has already been set to an instance of another class. Consider the following code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 42

    def __add__(self, value):
        print("Incrementing a of A by {}".format(value))
        self.a += value


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()
        self.b = 10

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        print("Setting {} of B to {}".format(attr, value))
        super(B, self).__setattr__(attr, value)


b = B()
print(b.b)
print(b.a)
b.b = 11
b.a += 1
print(b.b)
print(b.a)
```

When run, the code above produces the following output:

```
Setting a of B to <__main__.A object at 0x7f5e25438410>
Setting b of B to 10
10
<__main__.A object at 0x7f5e25438410>
Setting b of B to 11
Incrementing a of A by 1
Setting a of B to None
11
None
```

Obviously, `b.a` is correctly looked up and incremented. However, after the successful lookup, Python is attempting to create a new attribute of `b` called `a`. Why is that happending?

Comment: Maybe your `__add__(self, value)` method should return an instance of A?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question based on Jan Willems' comment:

Having `__add__(self, value)` return `self` fixes the described issue despite not being obvious. The documentation for the method ([`__add__` Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__add__#object.__add__) ) does not mention that `__add__` should return anything when it is successful, which is where my confusion stemmed from.

Comment: idiomatically, `__add__` should not work in-place, you should use `__iadd__`, which is for `my_object += whatever`. Note, when no `__iadd__` exists, it defers to `__add__`, but if you only use `__add__` then counter-intuitively, `my_object + whatever` mutates `my_object`